# Missing nominaliser in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, nominalization

Just read [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29367/question-with-this-sentence-%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9F%E3%81%97%E3%81%AF%E3%81%88%E3%82%92%E3%81%BF%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8C%E3%81%99%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99) and it reminded me of something I'd been meaning to ask.

> 私、そんなに悪いことしてるおぼえないんだけど...
>
> I don't remember doing such bad things but...

Is the lack of a nominaliser on してる an error in my book or is there a reason this grammar is allowed? The book seems to be written in a very colloquial style so I was wondering if it's just natural but lazy Japanese.

Comment: And how do you parse おぼえない?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably confused because it looks like two verbs together, してる and 覚えない (neg. of 覚える)

But it's actually a relative clause ending in してる, modifying the noun 覚え, with a particle (は or が) colloquially being dropped between 覚え and ない.

[覚え](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%A6%9A%E3%81%88-454303) as a noun here is definition 2 in this dictionary:

> 記憶に残っている事柄。また、思い当たること。心覚え。「この顔には覚えがある」「身に覚えがない」

So `memory`, `recollection`, etc.

Answer (score 7):

私、そんなに悪いことしてる**おぼえ**(は)ないんだけど..
I think you parse it now.

Comment: Oops!!Late by 1~2 minutes.

Comment: Don't worry! More answers are good, and the same thing being explained in different ways by different people can be helpful :)