# How should I translate からである in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, translation, business-japanese, particle-から

日本の輸出をストップさせるために、円高が進行していたからである。

I know that normally it explains reason, but if I translate it with that meaning, the sentence doesn't make sense. And I've found this usage of からである, in other sentence too...

しかも、地価をのぞけば、物価も安定していたからである (for example)

Thank you very much!!

Comment: If i say である is the literary equivalent to です does that help? If you could give us your attempt to translate maybe we could help you understand it more.

Comment: "In order to stop japanese exports, because the endaka was in progress" and "Moreover, if we exclude land prices, because the price was also stable"

But it doesn't make sense

Comment: I translated your sentence as "Because yen was appreciating to make Japanese exports stop" and " Because the price was also stable except land price". They make sense, don't they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「[日本]{にほん}の[輸出]{ゆしゅつ}をストップさせるために、[円高]{えんだか}が[進行]{しんこう}していた**からである**。」

I *think* I know why you do not think this sentence makes sense.  (The sentence makes perfect sense, I assure you.)

「～～からである」 indeed expresses the reason for a result (or the cause of an effect), but you are looking for the description of the result/effect within that one sentence, are you not?  If so, the result/effect is ***not*** mentioned within the sentence.  ***It should be mentioned in the preceding sentences***.

> "***That is because*** the yen was accelerating its appreciation in order to stop Japanese export business."

The same thing could be said about your second example sentence.  The result/effect is not mentioned in it.

> 「しかも、[地価]{ちか}をのぞけば、[物価]{ぶっか}も[安定]{あんてい}していたからである。」
>
> "***That is because*** the prices, except for land prices, had become stabilized as well."

Comment: Interesting that you used "accelerating"?  I would to say that "increasing" would be a better word here?

Comment: Thank you very much!! That's a type of sentence costruction that sounds a little odd in my language ( I'm not english). You made it perfectly clear thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is から + である。

から = because

である is a more formal version of です

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand of ishikun's answer.

- 日本{にほん}の輸出{ゆしゅつ}をストップさせるために、円高{えんだか}が進行{しんこう}していたからである。
- To enable exports from Japan to stop due to progressive Appreciation of the Yen

And for your second sentence,

- しかも、地価{ちか}をのぞけば、物価{ぶっか}も安定{あんてい}していたからである
- On top of that, leaving out Land prices, it is from prices (of commodities) stabilizing

Also, the following 「である」is very rarely used in spoken Japanese, but is widely used in written form.

- 円高が進行していた**からである**

Would be said something like this,

- 円高が進行していた**からだ**

Answer (score 0):

Yes that から denotes a reason. 「AはBからである」 is "The reason of A is B", "A because B", etc.

> - 眠いのは遅くまでテレビを見ていたからだ。
>     (You are/I am/etc) sleepy because (I/you/etc) stayed up late watching TV.
> - 空が青いのは太陽光が空気によって散乱されるからです。
>     The sky is blue because the sunlight is scattered by the air.

(The の before は is the [nominalizer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29367/5010).)

If the first part ("Aは") is missing, the sentence denotes a reason referring to the previous sentence (i.e., "It's because ～").

> - 遅くまでテレビを見ていたからだ。
>     It's because (you/I/etc) stayed up late watching TV.
> - 日本の輸出をストップさせるために、円高が進行していた**からである**。
>     **It's because** the value of yen was increasing in order to stop (stagnate) exports from Japan.

Please provide us the previous context if the sentence still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Could you point out where the implication of "stagnate" is?

Comment: I just wanted to be clear that this "stop" does not mean halting exports completely but just means slowing it down. But you're right, it might be redundant.

Comment: Agreed, the context is just not there to make an educated guess I think.  But, that certainly make sense.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: By the way the previous context of the two sentences is:
(1) 円高がすすみはじめたころ、日本経済は、輸出産業を中心に景気がおちた。円高不況である。日本の輸出をストップさせるために、円高が進行していたからである。


(2) 円高で、輸入原材料の価格がやすくなったことだけが原因ではない。円高を前提にした、日本企業の経営努力も、原因のひとつである。海外生産の拡大、事業の多角経営化、内需産業への転換などがそれである。しかも、地下をのぞけば、物価も安定していたからである。