# I like to do 'Verbs'

Tags: verbs

How do you say that you like to do a verb?

Some sentences i need translating are:

1. I like to watch TV
2. I like to sleep
3. I like to eat Pasta
4. I like learning languages

Comment: Related: [Question with this sentence わたしはえをみるのがすきです](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29367/5010)

Comment: I've asked about the closure of this question on meta: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1804/is-closing-this-as-a-translation-request-an-over-reaction

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you turn the verb into a noun using の or こと. Generally, <verb>+こと or の means something along the lines of "the act of doing <verb>". For example,

テレビを見るのが好きです。
terebi o miru no ga suki desu
I like to watch TV.

寝ることが好きです。
neru koto ga suki desu
I like to sleep.