# Translation: Wear glasses to read

Tags: translation, syntax

I’m preparing for a written exam at a beginner level and trying to expand a simple sentence, (He) wears glasses:

> めがね を かけて います。

Into: “he wears glasses to read”, as in not all the time.

My first thought was:

> めがね を かけて よんで います。

, but it means, I think: (He) is wearing glasses and reading.

I appreciate the answer might be a bit out of my depth, but it really bothers me now. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to say this would be:

> よむのに めがねを かけて います。

の after よむ is a [nominalizer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29367/5010). に is a particle that can mark a purpose. So よむのに is like "for reading" in English.

You can also say:

> - よむために めがねを かけて います。
> - よむときは めがねを かけて います。

～ために is another way of saying "in order to" (see [this](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/japanese-grammar-tame.html)). ～とき is "when ～" (see [this](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/toki-in-japanese.html)). There are small difference in meaning, but I think you can choose which is best in your case.

As you have correctly guessed, "めがね を かけて よんで います。" is a correct Japanese sentence, but it means "He is reading wearing glasses."