# How do I know when to use の with が in a "good/bad at" sentence?

Tags: particles, nominalization

In all sentences that describe someone being good or bad at something, as well as liking/disliking doing something, the particle が is used. I know for a fact that you use が for like/dislike.

In some sentences, the particles のが are there.
i.e: "I don't really like doing the laundry"

> 私はせんたくをするのが好きじゃないです。

Why is there a のが instead of just が？

Comment: This の is something called a nominalizer. Does this answer your question? [Question with this sentence わたしはえをみるのがすきです](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29367/question-with-this-sentence-%e3%82%8f%e3%81%9f%e3%81%97%e3%81%af%e3%81%88%e3%82%92%e3%81%bf%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8c%e3%81%99%e3%81%8d%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99)

Answer (score -1):

のがis used with a verb when the focus is shifted to the verb despite the sentence having a subject defined by は. It was similar to usage to のは, but with different focus.
Like in the example the subject is watasi, but the focus is on sentaku suru.