# Is it necessary to use the の particle (along with が) when saying "I like (something)"?

Tags: particles, particle-の, nominalization

I have read this sentence:

私は絵を見るのが好きです。

and I don't understand why is the の required. As far as I understand, が is used to indicate the subject of the sentence, in this case a picture (what is liked). My understanding is that が should be enough. In addition, I have translated that sentence (without the の) with Google Translate and it works as well.

Comment: Just a note about machine translation like Google Translate. It will assume you have given it correct Japanese and do its best to make sense of anything entered, even if it has mistakes or is pure nonsense. You aren't going to be warned by it that the grammar is wrong or necessarily get nonsense English in return.

Comment: Related: [Question with this sentence わたしはえをみるのがすきです](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29367/5010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, the の particle essentially turns the dictionary form of the verb 「見る」- to watch, into 「見るの」- watching, in the sense that it can now function as a noun in the sentence and become a subject or object. You will also often see 「こと」 used this way.

So, yes, it is required. It is not the possessive の particle that you are thinking of, but a different の particle.

Edit - just to clarify - it's required when it's a verb, not when the thing you like is already a noun.